# SQL procedure - Multiple value

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have this procedure :

```
BEGIN 
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; 
  DECLARE `id_var` varchar(255);
  DECLARE `cur1` CURSOR FOR
  SELECT `id` FROM `clients` 
  WHERE `status` = 'Active';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tblquota_nc`;
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblquota_nc` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255),
  `pack_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pack_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `quota` int(11) NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
  OPEN cur1;
  read_loop: LOOP
     FETCH NEXT
     FROM cur1
     INTO id_var;
     IF done THEN
         LEAVE read_loop;
     END IF;

     SELECT clients.id as `User ID`, `email`, `packageid` as `Pack ID`, `name` as `Pack`, (CASE
        WHEN `name` = "Basic" THEN '10'
        WHEN `name` = "Silver" THEN '100'
        WHEN `name` = "Gold" THEN '1000'
        ELSE '10'
     END) as Quota INTO @mid, @mail, @p_id, @packname, @quota
     FROM `clients` 
     INNER JOIN `tblhosting` ON clients.id = tblhosting.userid 
     INNER JOIN `tblproducts` ON tblhosting.packageid = tblproducts.id 
     WHERE clients.status = 'Active' 
     AND tblhosting.domainstatus = 'Active'
     AND clients.id = id_var;
     IF (SELECT id FROM tblquota_nc WHERE user_id = @mid) THEN
        BEGIN
        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            if (@mid IS NOT NULL AND @p_id IS NOT NULL AND @packname IS NOT NULL) then
                INSERT INTO tblquota_nc (user_id, email, pack_id, pack_name, quota) VALUES (@mid, @mail, @p_id, @packname, @quota);
            end if;
        END;
        END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur1;
END
```

It seems like I have an error because the `SELECT` statment return several values. I thought doing another loop with these results to make an insert into the new table. I want to make a new table from these information.

table **clients**:

```
id | email          | status
----------------------------
1  | user1@mail.com | Active
2  | user2@mail.com | Inactive
3  | user3@mail.com | Active
```

table **tblhosting**

```
id | userid | packageid | domainstatus 
------------------------------------------------
1  | 1      | 2         | Active
2  | 2      | 3         | Active
3  | 3      | 1         | Active
```

table **tblproducts**

```
id | name 
-----------
1  | Basic
2  | Silver
3  | Gold
```

I expect result like :

```
id | user_id | email          | pack_id | pack_name | quota
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | user1@mail.com | 2       | Silver    | 100
2  | 2       | user2@mail.com | 3       | Gold      | 1000
3  | 3       | user3@mail.com | 1       | Basic     | 10
```

If I put max in the case statment, it will work but will not show all data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a stored procedure to do this. Just use [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html) syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE tblquota_nc (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) AS
     SELECT c.id as user_id
         , c.`email`
         , h.`packageid` as pack_id
         , p.`name` as pack_name
         , (CASE WHEN `name` = "Basic" THEN '10'
                 WHEN `name` = "Silver" THEN '100'
                 WHEN `name` = "Gold" THEN '1000'
                 ELSE '10'
            END) as quota
     FROM `clients` c
     LEFT JOIN `tblhosting` h ON c.id = h.userid 
     INNER JOIN `tblproducts` p ON h.packageid = p.id 
     ORDER BY c.id;
```

Output from `SELECT * FROM tblquota_nc`:

```
id  user_id     email           pack_id     pack_name   quota
1   1           user1@mail.com  2           Silver      100
2   2           user2@mail.com  3           Gold        1000
3   3           user3@mail.com  1           Basic       10
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=e28c7a822202aece15c2d9d14de7ab93)